# Google Apps Script HTML Form - Put Data into Spreadsheet using Variables for Form Fields

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, forms

I have a small rota application in Google Sheets.

There is a tab that lists the types of jobs/roles.  This list can change, e.g. last week a new role was added to the list.

I have an HTML form for adding new employees to the rota application.

The form uses the list of roles in the spreadsheet to dynamically create the input fields on the form on my addPerson.html:

```
<? var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); //get the currently open & active workbook
     var roles =ss.getSheetByName("Roles");  // get the Roles tab
     var roleValues = roles.getRange(1,1,roles.getLastRow(),1).getValues();?>
  <table>      
  <? for (i = 0; i < roleValues.length; i++) { ?>

  <tr><td><?= roleValues[i]?>:</td><td> £</td><td> <input type = "number" name=<?= String(roleValues[i]).replace(/\s/g,'') ?> id=<?= String(roleValues[i]).replace(/\s/g,'') ?>/></td></tr>
  <? } ?>
  </table>
```

That's all working fine.

Where I am having trouble is in accessing the data from the form for the fields that are created in the code above.  I can access the other data without a problem.

Here is how I am trying to get the fields in question in my code.gs:

```
for(i=0; i<lastRole; i++){
  nextRow++;
  var role = String(roleValues[i]).replace(/\s/g,'');
  Logger.log(role);
  if(form.role !== null){
    Logger.log(form.role);
    rates.getRange(nextRow, 1).setValue(name);
    rates.getRange(nextRow, 2).setValue(form.role);
    rates.getRange(nextRow, 3).setValue(rate);
    rates.getRange(nextRow, 4).setValue(team);

  }
}
```

The initial definition of `role` works fine, but using that as `form.role` doesn't work, as you can see in the logs.

```
[18-03-16 04:04:43:634 PDT] Bar
[18-03-16 04:04:43:635 PDT] undefined
[18-03-16 04:04:43:643 PDT] BarB
[18-03-16 04:04:43:643 PDT] undefined
[18-03-16 04:04:43:651 PDT] BarSup
[18-03-16 04:04:43:652 PDT] undefined
[18-03-16 04:04:43:660 PDT] DM
[18-03-16 04:04:43:661 PDT] undefined
[18-03-16 04:04:43:669 PDT] DT
[18-03-16 04:04:43:670 PDT] undefined
[18-03-16 04:04:43:678 PDT] FoHC
[18-03-16 04:04:43:679 PDT] undefined
[18-03-16 04:04:43:688 PDT] Maint
[18-03-16 04:04:43:688 PDT] undefined
[18-03-16 04:04:43:697 PDT] TM
[18-03-16 04:04:43:698 PDT] undefined
[18-03-16 04:04:43:707 PDT] VT
[18-03-16 04:04:43:707 PDT] undefined
```

How do I work through the list of HTML form input fields to get the data into a spreadsheet?

Comment: Show the output of `Logger.log(form)`

Comment: There's nothing in your html code above that suggests your form has an input control with the value of "name" attribute set to "role". All "name" attributes are set to be equal to roleValues[i]. So my guess is, form.role is undefined simply because it doesn't exist.

Comment: @tehhowch - here is the output of `Logger.log(form)`: `[18-03-16 17:07:49:266 GMT] {BarB=8, BarSup=, DT=, Maint=, Bar=, baseRate=8, FoHC=, name=Test, DM=, TM=, team=Box, VT=}`

Comment: @AntonDementiev - The names are set programatically.  The `<?=` tag is used to populate the HTML form with the output of the code within the tag.  You can see from the log information above that each of the elements has the required name.  What I am seeking to achieve is that the content in the field `BarB` is added to a spreadsheet.  However, I don't want to call `BarB` explicitly - I want to create that call using variables, i.e. pick up `BarB` from the list of roles on the spreadsheet and then use that to find the corresponding value from the form and put it into another sheet.

Comment: `form.role` doesn't exist. However, `form[role]` does.

Comment: The way your data are organized isn’t very obvious. You mentioned you have the sheet with the list of roles - where is the new employee record supposed to go? Is it on the same sheet as the job types?  Also, if your plan is to add new employees, one at a time, why not pre-populate a drop-down list with the list of jobs and then let the user select one instead of displaying 8 inputs? I know how templated HTML works in GAS, but have trouble understanding why you are even calling form.role when none of the DOM elements in your template follows this pattern “element[name=‘role’]”

Comment: @AntonDementiev The destination is not important in solving this problem. A person can have multiple jobs, and different rates of pay for each of those jobs, e.g. a manager can cover a bar shift. I need to hold a rate of pay for each person in each role. Selecting from a list is no good. That's why I present a list of all the available roles and when the person record is set up, the user enters a rate of pay against the various jobs that an employee is trained for.  Another user on here has solved the problem for me, it was just about how I needed to reference the form data. Thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having here is that the dot notation for an object is not interpreted as a variable - it is interpreted as a literal. So for `form.role`, the engine is looking at the object `form`, and inspecting the property named `"role"`, even if in your environment you have a variable named `role` present.

To obtain the value of the property named by the value of the variable named `role`, you must use bracket notation: `form[role]`.

Consider reviewing the MDN resource on [Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Comment: Perfect.  That solved things.  Thanks for the advice - as a self taught amateur, knowing what to search for is difficult sometimes.  I guess after reading the documentation, I'm not entirely certain when to use bracket notation over dot notation, but at least I know about bracket notation now and can try that in the future.